# How to format CCK fields printed in custom template

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have managed to print date and dollar amount CCK fields on a custom print.tpl.php template file (associated with the [Printer, email and PDF versions module](https://drupal.org/project/print)), but they are showing up in a different format than how I have them displayed in the CCK field itself.

The date is showing up like this:  2012-06-01 00:00:00
Instead of like this: June 1, 2012

And the dollar amount is showing up like this: 10000
Instead of like this: $10,000

Here are the code snippets:

```
    <?php if(isset($node->field_invoice_due_date['und'][0]['value'])) { 
          print $node->field_invoice_due_date['und'][0]['value'];
   }
 ?>


    <?php if(isset($node->field_invoice_amount_to_bill['und'][0]['value'])) { 
          print $node->field_invoice_amount_to_bill['und'][0]['value'];
   }
 ?>
```

Can anyone direct me on how I can change those two snippets to output their values in the formats I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually date() takes a timestamp so the code should be:

```
<?php if(isset($node->field_invoice_due_date['und'][0]['value'])) { 
          print date('F j, Y', strtotime($node->field_invoice_due_date['und'][0]['value']));
   }
 ?>
```

and to insert the thousands separator, you can use number_format():

```
<?php if(isset($node->field_invoice_amount_to_bill['und'][0]['value'])) { 
          print "$". number_format($node->field_invoice_amount_to_bill['und'][0]['value']);
   }
 ?>
```

if you wish to avoid a preprocess function.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!  Two follow-up items... I also have a Computed Field in this particular content type. How can I print the contents of that Computed Field and retain its formatting? I have a Textarea block as well; how can I print that while retaining its HTML formatting?

Comment: Welcome. This should really be posed as a new question. Assuming you have a 'Print' display type, set the Computed field to 'Unsanitised' and the Textarea should work with 'Full HTML'. If this does not work, post a new question.

Comment: Changing the textarea field's text format to "Raw HTML" (a format I created that is devoid of any HTML help) and adding line breaks where necessary allowed that field to display in HTML format. Not a perfect solution, but workable for now I suppose. My computed fields are already set to "Unsanitized". I have posted a new question, here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75432/how-to-print-formatted-contents-of-computed-field-and-full-html-textarea-in-a-cu

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to preprocess these elements into the template and format them to the way you want.

Let's take this practical example.  Let's say we have a content type of 'blog' and we wanted to preprocess the same variables as above to be used in the template file...

```
/**
 * Preprocess variables for node.tpl.php
 *
 * @see node.tpl.php
 */
function theme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['type'] == 'blog') {
    if (isset($vars['field_invoice_due_date'][0]['value'])) {
      // Makes June 1, 2012 format from the time provided
      $vars['date_format'] = date("F j, Y", strtotime($vars['field_invoice_due_date'][0]['value']));
    } else {
      $vars['date_format'] = '';
    }
    if (isset($vars['field_invoice_amount_to_bill'][0]['value'])) {
      // you can use whatever function to format the money value, this is just an example.
      $vars['amount_to_bill'] = "$". number_format('%i', $vars['field_invoice_amount_to_bill'][0]['value']);
    } else {
      $vars['amount_to_bill'] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

if your moving these fields into a custom template, than you can preprocess with this hook as well:

```
 /**
 *
 * Implements hook_preprocess
 *
 * @param $variables
 * @param $hook
 */
function hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'custom_template') {
    // do your preprocess magic here, you can find the variables by either dsm() or print_r()
  }
}
```

then, in the template do this:

```
<?php print $date_format; ?>
<?php print $amount_to_bill; ?>
```

Comment: The function [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows.

Comment: ahh, gotcha - I'm such a linux guru.  Thanks for the strtotime()

Comment: Glad to help. It is a good answer. I will let you do this edit. Remove the formatting string:  `string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )`. :-)